# Primary sources for Persian land of Shadu-kam?

Tags: persian, shahnameh

I'd like to find the primary sources (if any) for a Persian mythical land called Shadu-kam. It's supposed to be the realm of the Peris, a kind of fairyland, but I can't seem to find much about it.

I discovered the name in Umberto Eco's *The Book of Legendary Lands*, where it's described very briefly:

> ...Persian romances often mention the blissful land of Shadu-kam.

I started digging, and I found a bit more detail in Thomas Keightley's [The Fairy Mythology, Volume 1](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/41006/41006-h/41006-h.htm), published in 1828. I have no idea if Keightley is trustworthy, but he writes:

> Jinnestân is the common appellation of the whole of this ideal region.
>   Its respective empires were divided into many kingdoms, containing
>   numerous provinces and cities. **Thus in the Peri-realms we meet with
>   the luxuriant province of Shad-u-kâm (Pleasure and Delight)**, with
>   its magnificent capital Juherabâd (Jewel-city), whose two kings
>   solicited the aid of Cahermân against the Deevs, and also the stately
>   Amberabâd (Amber-city), and others equally splendid. The metropolis of
>   the Deev-empire is named Ahermanabâd (Aherman's city); and imagination
>   has lavished its stores in the description of the enchanted castle,
>   palace, and gallery of the Deev monarch, Arzshenk.

It's an old book, so transliterations don't always match their modern versions.

Regarding the hero Cahermân mentioned above, he later adds:

> The Cahermân Nâmeh is a romance in Turkish. Cahermân was the father of
>   Sâm, the grandfather of the celebrated Roostem.

This would seem to make Cahermân match the [Nariman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nariman_(father_of_S%C4%81m)) of the Shahnameh. But I haven't been able to find anything about Shadu-kam in the Shahnameh, nor can I find any information anywhere on this Cahermân Nâmeh romance.

I've found other books that mention Shadu-kam, but most seem like they're just repeating Keightley. The Keightley book might even be Eco's source, but it's hard to tell.

Does anyone know of any primary sources?

Comment: Hi Brian. I've taken an initial look at this question. I think you're right when you say that most of the sources that mention Shad-u-kâm are copying Keightley. You are also right to be skeptical of Keightley: he was writing when the field of folklore was just getting started, which means that accuracy wasn't a really big concern of his. Looking at his writings, my initial impression is that he was motivated by a desire to project Christian concepts onto Persian mythology (although a lot of parallels do exist between the two, Keightley seems to have gone above and beyond in this).

Comment: You're on the right track when you mention the similarities between Caherman and Nariman: remember, translation techniques have improved vastly since Keightley was alive. I could be wrong, but my initial impression is that the best way to answer this question would be to try to search for parallels between Shad-u-kâm and some other concept in persian literature. However, keep in mind that it's possible that Keightley made this story up: at the time he was writing it was really common for researchers to pass off stories they wrote as genuine literature.